# Where is the serial port flag CRTSXOFF on Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, solaris

I'm trying to port some Solaris serial port code to Linux, however the XOn / XOff symbol typically found in `termios.h` seems to be missing.

```
// ...
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

// ...
int config_port(int fd, int timeout)
{
  struct termios options; /* Holds the port option flags */
  int status;             /* Holds return value of system calls */
  int min_chars;          /* Holds the minimum number of characters to read
                           * before returning. */

   // ...

   options.c_cflag &= ~( CRTSXOFF | CRTSCTS );     // <<-- HERE
```

Of course, Linux GCC doesn't know `CRTSXOFF`:

```
# gcc -c -g serial.c
serial.c: In function ‘config_port’:
serial.c:125:25: error: ‘CRTSXOFF’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  125 |   options.c_cflag &= ~( CRTSXOFF | CRTSCTS );
```

On Solaris, this symbol is certainly defined in `termios.h`:

```
# find /usr/include -iname \*.h -exec grep CRTSXOFF {} /dev/null \;
/usr/include/sys/termios.h:#define      CRTSXOFF 010000000000
```

But on Linux the same command finds me nothing.

Is this symbol called something else on Linux?

Comment: *"the XOn / XOff symbol typically found in termios.h seems to be missing ...  Linux GCC doesn't know `CRTSXOFF`"* -- You seem confused.  Man pages that I found mention that `CRTSXOFF` enables inbound ***hardware*** flow control, whereas you mention software flow control.  What exactly are you try to do?  Did you  try reading the Linux **man** page for termios?

Comment: BTW there are other/more attribute names that are unique to Solaris that are not in Linux.  See https://flylib.com/books/en/3.224.1.275/1/

Answer (score 0):

Found it: under Linux `CRTSXOFF` is implemented as `IXOFF`.